# Enable compiler optimisation only for individual functions/files

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on a C++ code in Visual Studio 2012 environment.
The code base is not very huge (contained in around 10-12 source files). The execution time for some of the functions in my project is huge (say 10 sec in REL mode, 50 sec in DEBUG mode)

Now while debugging, I often require to look at functions executing towards the end of my application lifetime. Is there a way to disable compiler optimisation only for specific functions and/or files in my project.
This would enable me to have optimised execution for some of the computationally extensive functions

NOTE: I had erroneously mentioned "debug symbols" instead of "compiler optimisation" previously. I was basically asking this questions w.r.t. compiler optimisation because of which it can become difficult to inspect variable values while debugging with break points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn optimization on or off for specific files in the properties->C/C++->Optimization dialog.  This is the same dialog you would use for the whole project, but the per file settings will override the project settings.

You can also surround particular functions or areas of code with `#pragma optimize( "", off )` and `#pragma optimize( "", on )` if you prefer to do it that way.

Either way you'll want to generate debug symbols for the whole program.  Having them there doesn't slow anything down and allows you to debug the optimized code if you want to.  It's more difficult since local variables and such are often not correct in the watch window and line numbers may not exactly line up, but between that and the disassembly view you can usually tell what's going on.

Comment: I can selectively disable optimizations, but it seems (?) from the docs that I can't selectively *enable* them. That is, I have a hot loop in a templated library that I'd like to be optimized in all builds, even "debug" builds. Is that possible?

Comment: `#pragma optimize("t", on)` before the code and `#pragma optimize("", off)` around the code in question may do what you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=msvc-170 It also might not, because templates. You probably want to ifdef them to only be active in debug builds so you don't mess up release build settings.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is something like this what you are talking about?: https://godbolt.org/z/TKd8dq6ao

Answer (score 0):

You can use _DEBUG macro in the code. You can define this macro specific to a file then remove it at the end of the file by undef

```
#ifndef _DEBUG //enable debug
#define _DEBUG

...//your code

#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG  //disable debug
#undef _DEBUG
#endif
```

Here is the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb575z2.aspx

Comment: Actually the question was meant for compiler optimisation. Ninja's solution finally worked for me.